# Is this counter-intuitive result actually correct?

Tags: differential-geometry, definite-integrals

I was trying to calculate the surface area of part of a sphere. The result seems counter-intuitive. I have found that the surface area of a sphere increases linearly.

Consider the circle, centre $(r,0)$ and radius $r>0$. This has equation $(x-r)^2 + y^2 = r^2$. For $y>0$, we can write $y$ as a function of $x$. Direct calculation shows that $y(x) = \sqrt{2rx-x^2}$ for all $0 < x < 2r$.

The usual formula for rotating the graph of a curve (given as a function of $x$) around the $x$-axis to find the surface area of revolution is
$$A = 2\pi \int_{x_1}^{x_2} y\sqrt{1+(y')^2} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

In my case, I have the limits $x_1=0$ and $x_2=h \le 2r$. We have
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
A &=& 2\pi \int_0^h \sqrt{2rx-x^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{(r-x)^2}{2rx-x^2}} \, \mathrm{d}x \\ \\ \\
&=&2\pi\int_0^h \sqrt{2rx-x^2}\sqrt{\frac{r^2}{2rx-x^2}} \, \mathrm{d}x \\ \\ \\
&=&2\pi\int_0^h r\, \mathrm{d}x \\ \\ \\
&=&2\pi r h
\end{eqnarray*}$$

This gives two correct results: when $h=0$ we have $A=0$ and when $h=2r$ we have $A=4\pi r^2$. However, it seems counter-intuitive that the area should be a linear function in $h$. For example, let $B(a,b)$ be the "belt" bounded by $x=a$ and $x=b$. Two belts of the same width should have different surface areas depending on how close their centres are to $x=r$. **Surely?**

Comment: @CalvinLin I got $A=2\pi rh$ which is a linear function of $h$. Notice that $r>0$ is a constant.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread.

Comment: Nice question. Seemed a bit shocking, but it is actually quite intuitive if you think about it. +1

Comment: @Sabyasachi It seems "plausible" after thinking about it. If you cut an onion in a slice that contains one of the "poles" then there's a lot of surface area that curves away from the cut towards the pole. If you cut a slice at the equator then the slice has a much wider radius but doesn't have any "down the side" surface. I still find it quite amazing. Would the same be true for an ellipsoid?

Comment: @FlybyNight maybe. I am making sense of the sphere by your belt example. And "sliding" the belt up and down. If this gets a nice explanation by tommorow, okay. Otherwise I am posting another question about the ellipsoid. Good day/night depending on your location

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed correct, and was already observed by Archimedes in his treatise [On the Sphere and Cylinder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Sphere_and_Cylinder). The translation of his work (with modernized notation) is availible in Heath's book *The Works of Archimedes*. See [Proposition 42](http://books.google.si/books?id=hdw5AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=heath+archimedes+proposition+42&source=bl&ots=WmIgp1fxm6&sig=dqKNLBzmY6qtTuJ40U3sflQFG7I&hl=en&sa=X&ei=crNBU4m1A4rMygP5zYFg&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=heath%20archimedes%20proposition%2042&f=false) and [Proposition 43](http://books.google.si/books?id=OCwl1dK0_U8C&pg=PA53&dq=heath+archimedes+proposition+43&hl=en&sa=X&ei=S7RBU_2QOObjywP434DoAw&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=heath%20archimedes%20proposition%2043&f=false).

The phrasing of Proposition 42 may be a bit strange for our modern ears: it says that the surface area of the spherical cap is equal to the area of the circle whose radius is equal to the segment with one end-point being the top of the spherical cap and the other one lying on the circle at the bottom of the cap. This segment has length $\sqrt{2rh}$ in your notation, which means that surface area of the cap is $\pi(\sqrt{2rh})^2=2\pi rh$, which amounts to your result.

Comment: Hi Dejan. Thanks for the link. I've looked at the link and I can't seem to see anything that relates to my question. It links the *total* volume and *total* surface area of a sphere to a cylinder. However, a sphere has a non-constant cross-section while a cylinder does have a constant cross-section.

Comment: @FlybyNight: Hello, I apologize, I was citing Wikipedia by memory and forgot to check if the result was mentioned there. I've expanded the answer to clarify. This might also interest you: http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Apostol496-508.pdf.

Comment: Interesting corollary: take a sphere and cut it up into 4 pieces by making a cut along the equator, then 2 cuts on the latitudes halfway between the equator and each pole. Which piece has the largest area? Ans: the areas are all equal. (My professor posed this question to introduce toric varieties at an MAA sectional meeting.)